# I'm not able to drag after searched location is entered on Google Place Picker API

Tags: java, android, gps, location, gmsplacepicker

So this is what happens. When I start Google Place Picker Intent, it lets me choose places around my location or it gives me the option to search a place.

But, I wanted the ability to even choose a place in the area around a searched location. i.e drag the marker after I search a location.

But, when I search a location and choose one, it just gives me [this option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KDfGt.png).

I need help with this. Thank you